# Interface wlan0mon: ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device

Tags: aircrack-ng

I'm having trouble with aircrack-ng.When I run the command:airodump-ng wlan0mon
is giving the following error:
Interface wlan0mon: 
ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device

Comment: you need change wlan0 to wlan0mon using airmon-ng sir

Comment: not working!!!!

Comment: how you do step using airmon-ng sir, please edit your question with the output sir.

Comment: Interface wlan0mon: 
ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device

Comment: use type `airmon-ng start wlan0` instead `airmon-ng` sir

Comment: I have done this

Comment: what the output said sir?

Comment: Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to run 'airmon-ng check kill'

  PID Name
15292 avahi-daemon
15293 avahi-daemon
15445 NetworkManager
15456 wpa_supplicant
15459 dhclient

PHY Interface Driver  Chipset

phy0 wlp5s0  ath9k  Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

Comment: you get interface wlan0 to wlp5s0 as mon0, and then you can use airdump-ng sir

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `wlan0` to `wlan0mon` using `airmon-ng`

and then type,

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

the output :

```
Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after a short period of time, you may want to run 'airmon-ng check kill' 

PID Name 
15292 avahi-daemon 
15293 avahi-daemon 
15445 NetworkManager 
15456 wpa_supplicant 
15459 dhclient 

PHY Interface   Driver Chipset 
phy0    wlp5s0  ath9k   Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

you get interface wlan0 to wlp5s0 as mon0, after that you can use `airodump-ng`, `aireplay-ng` and also `aircrack-ng` sir.

Hope this helps.